# Google Sheet Query - Building Reference Array Dynamically

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have multiple tabs in a file and want to merge the same range to a master tab.

I did a Query

```
=QUERY({source1!AR5:AU;source1!AR5:AU}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null order by Col1", 0)
```

But at the end I will have more and more tabs (around 30), and I don't want to change my query manually each time. how can i do?

I saw somewhere that I can use macros to create a function, do you have an idea of the code?
I just want to have something easy where I have added in another tab all my tab names

Comment: @Calculuswhiz yes, it is the same range in each added sheet

Comment: @NoemieRousseau Why do you keep track of the data on different tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var allSheets = [];
  // Append more names if you want to exclude more
  // Since 'query' is master sheet, excluded it as well
  // Remove 'query' below if you want to include it in the formula
  var excludedTabs = ['other', 'random', 'query'];
  
  sheets.forEach(function (sheet){
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (!excludedTabs.includes(sheetName)){
      allSheets.push(sheetName);
    }
  });

  // Set formula in A1 cell in "query" sheet
  // Modify A1 to change the cell
  var cell = ss.getSheetByName('query').getRange("A1"); 
  cell.setFormula("=QUERY({" + allSheets.join('!AR5:AU;') + "!AR5:AU}, \"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null order by Col1\", 0)");
}
```

This will set the formula to `A1` of the sheet `query`, feel free to change where to set the formula by changing `A1` and `query`.

You can also add sheets to be excluded. Append it on the `excludedTabs` array.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Sample sheets were added to check the new sheet cases.

Expected formula was added. (excluding `query`, `random` and `other` sheets)

Comment: thanks a lot! it is almost something like this that I need, but I would like to select the tabs I want. (3 of them should not be considered in the macro and all the other ones yes). can you help?

Comment: Yes for sure @NoemieRousseau . If you can specify these tabs, it would be easy to adjust

Comment: so if I want my query in sheet "query", then i want to exclude other sheets called "other" & "random" and I want to consider all the rest in my query

Comment: awesome ! let me check !

Comment: so great ! it is working ! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi @NoemieRousseau, glad it did work. Anyways, I did modify it again for it to be more readable and easy to understand. Also, if your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer